# What values of $a$ does this integral converge for?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^1 \frac {x^a}{x-\sin x} dx$$

I tried comparison test and limit comparison test, but I didn't get to anything.

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true [...], it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts.  – From [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Comment: Your recent edit provides even less context than what you started with.  Please add context, perhaps including where you encountered this problem, what theorems or other similar problems you have worked on, or any approaches that you think could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing $\sin {x} = x -\frac{x^3}{3!}+o(x^3)$ using taylor series for $\sin{x}$, we get

$$x - \sin{x} = \frac{x^3}{3!}+o(x^3)$$

$$\implies \frac{x^a}{x-\sin{x}} = \frac{1}{\frac{x^{3-a}}{3!}+o(x^{3-a})}$$

If $ a \ge 3$, the highest power of $x$ in denominator is less than or equal to 0. So, finite limit for $\frac{x^a}{x-\sin{x}}$ exists at $x=0$  and is finite and continuous everywhere in $[0,1]$. So, it is integrable if $ a \ge 3$.

Similarly, if $a \le 2$, $\frac{x^a}{x-\sin{x}}$, highest power in denominator is greater than one and it diverges at $x=0$. It can be shown that the function is not integrable on any closed interval including $x=0$. Divergence of harmonic series can be used to show this.

Similarly, if $ 3 \gt a \gt 2$, $\frac{x^a}{x-\sin{x}}$, the function diverges at $x=0$.But it is similar to $x^{-p}$ where $p<1$ which can be shown to be integrable on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: Actually it should be $a>2$.  The integral diverges for $a=2$.